# Python multiprocessing - pipe find prime numbers in an interval

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

In python 3, I have to find prime numbers in an interval `[a,b]` using multiprocessing pipes in specific... Here is my code using  the `pool.map` method:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def isprime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return None
    for i in range(2, num):
         if (num % i) == 0:
            return None
    else:
        return num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, pool.map(isprime, range(0,30))))
    finish_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Program finished in {finish_time-start_time} seconds")
    print(result)
```

i didnt fully understand the pipe method  here is the code tht i found as an example while doing my research

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def parentData(parent):
    ''' This function sends the data for the child process '''
    parent.send(['Hello'])
    parent.close()

def childData(child):
    ''' This function sends the data for the parent process '''
    child.send(['Bye'])
    child.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent, child = Pipe()              # Create Pipe
    process1 = Process(target = parentData, args = (parent, ))      # Create a process for handling parent data
    process2 = Process(target = childData, args = (child, ))        # Create a process for handling child data
    process1.start()                    # Start the  parent process
    process2.start()                    # Start the child process
    print(parent.recv())                # Display data received from child (BYE)
    print(child.recv())                 # Display data received from parent (HELLO)
    process1.join()                     # Wait till the process completes its execution
    process2.join()
```

Can anyone show me an example of doing the multiprocessing of prime numbers with  pipes?

Comment: I gave you an answer to [ a question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133174) to which you made no comment right or wrong, so I no longer really know what you want. A `Pipe` instance cannot be shared among multiple consumers or multiple producers unless you serialize access to it; a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance does precisely that and will not block a producer just because nothing is being consumed, which is not the case for a `Pipe` instance. Your "pipe" example is *not* the way a `pipe` is *usually* used. What if you had more than 2 processes needing to send back data?

Comment: Also, if for example your `process2` needed to do many `send` calls, it would soon block until the main process finished reading whatever data `process1` sent back and was then able to start consuming with `child.recv()` calls.

Comment: im extremly sorry but i should've use pipes instead of the pool.map method in the first place see im really limited in terms of choicess i cant use any other methods but thosee who are a part of the processus regardless of their performence